# powershell multidimensionnal array group and table print

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I'm building an array with some values, like 
`$arr+=,(val1,val2)`

Now i want to group that array by count of `$arr[$i][1]` and print with formatted table. What I have done so far:

```
$t = @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="From";width=25},@{Expression={$_.Value};Label="Subject";width=25}
$arr | group | % { $h = @{} } { $h[$_.Name] = $_.Count } { $h | Format-Table $t; }
```

I know that this isn't right.. how can i accomplish this in a right way?
Basically i want to table print val1 val2 and the nr of count entries for val2

Comment: Can you give an example of input data and the result you want to receive.

Comment: how about this:

`$Arr | Group | Select -Property Name,Count | Format-Table -AutoSize`

Comment: @JPBlanc well an example `$val1="some1"; $val2="$some2"; $arr+=,($val1,$val2); $val2="some2"; $arr+=,($val1,$val2)` now i want to print the $arr array in a formatted table with 3 columns, 1 for $val1, 1 for $val2 and another one for counting $val2